# How to program a function to return the string repeated n times, separated by the string delim

Tags: computer-science

This is suppose to create a function that can return the string repeated n times, separated by the string delim desired by the user. What am I missing?

```
def repeat(string, n, delim) :
  return (string + delim) * (n - 1)


def main() :
  string = input("Enter a string: ")
  n = int(input("Enter the number of times repeat: "))
  delim = input("Enter the delim: ")

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the string to the last:

```
def repeat(string, n, delim) :
  return (string + delim) * (n - 1) + string


def main() :
  string = input("Enter a string: ")
  n = int(input("Enter the number of times repeat: "))
  delim = input("Enter the delim: ")
  print(repeat(string, n, delim))

main()
```

output:

```
Enter a string: hello
Enter the number of times repeat: 10
Enter the delim: ,
hello,hello,hello,hello,hello,hello,hello,hello,hello,hello
```